# RadioButtons messing up bound data

Tags: wpf, radio-button

In an `UserControl` (`TaskView1`) I'm binding several booleans to `RadioButtons`:

```
      <StackPanel>
                <RadioButton Content="Spell" IsChecked="{Binding IsSpell}"  />
                <RadioButton Content="Movement" IsChecked="{Binding IsMovement}"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Action" IsChecked="{Binding IsAction}" />
                <RadioButton Content="Find" IsChecked="{Binding IsFind}"/>
       </StackPanel>
```

This `UserControl` (`TaskView1`) is used to display the selected `Task` in a `TreeView` (note that I have two `DataTemplate` defined because there are two different type of `Task` and I want different views for each of them).

```
 <GroupBox Header="Selected Task">
            <GroupBox.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task1}">
                    <local:TaskView1/>
                </DataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Task2}">
                    <local:TaskView2/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupBox.Resources>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <ScrollViewer DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TaskTreeView}" Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
 </GroupBox>
```

The issue arises when I change the selection of tasks in my tree. As the radio buttons are exclusive I often find that the actual bound data of `Task1Instance1` has been changed when I've selected in the tree `Task1Instance2`.

Example:

Task A is selected in tree. It is a `Movement`.
Then the user selects Task B, and it is a `Spell`. What happens is that somehow the data of Task A is changed and now `IsMovement` is false, so no RadioButton is selected if the user selects Task A again.

Question:

Is this a common issue in WPF or I'm just messing up something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with a ComboBox that had SelectedIndex property set to ="0" in XAML.